# How to compare the elements in an array of hashes and keep only the most recent item

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

I am using the the below Array of Hashes and would like to only display the most recent hash based off the 'Datetime', if four certain parameters are the same. Let me provide an example using the code below...

If 'toy, kind, Stage, Step' are the same, then I would only like to store only that hash into a new array of hashes.

Original Array of Hashes

```
$VAR1 = [
      {
        'Color' => 'green',
        '2nd Color' => 'blue',
        '3rd Color' => 'yellow',
        'toy' => 'truck',
        'toy_type' => 'ford',
        'kind' => '4door',
        'Stage' => 'Production',
        'Step' => 'Platform',
        'Datetime' => '2012/06/08 01:49:19'
      },
      {
        'Color' => 'red',
        '2nd Color' => 'green',
        '3rd Color' => 'yellow',
        'toy' => 'truck',
        'toy_type' => 'ford',
        'kind' => '4door',
        'Stage' => 'Production',
        'Step' => 'Platform',
        'Datetime' => '2012/06/08 01:46:17'
      },
      {
        'Color' => 'red',
        '2nd Color' => 'blue',
        '3rd Color' => 'green',
        'toy' => 'truck',
        'toy_type' => 'chevy',
        'kind' => '4door',
        'Stage' => 'Production',
        'Step' => 'Platform',
        'Datetime' => '2012/06/08 01:52:14'
      },
      {
        'Color' => 'red',
        '2nd Color' => 'blue',
        '3rd Color' => 'yellow',
        'toy' => 'truck',
        'toy_type' => 'chevy',
        'kind' => '4door',
        'Stage' => 'Production',
        'Step' => 'Platform',
        'Datetime' => '2012/06/08 01:24:14'
      },
      {
        'Color' => 'white',
        '2nd Color' => 'blue',
        '3rd Color' => 'yellow',
        'toy' => 'truck',
        'toy_type' => 'gmc',
        'kind' => '4door',
        'Stage' => 'Production',
        'Step' => 'Platform',
        'Datetime' => '2012/06/08 06:24:14'
      },
```

New Array of Hashes I want saved to a variable:

```
$VAR2 = [
      {
        'Color' => 'green',
        '2nd Color' => 'blue',
        '3rd Color' => 'yellow',
        'toy' => 'truck',
        'toy_type' => 'ford',
        'kind' => '4door',
        'Stage' => 'Production',
        'Step' => 'Platform',
        'Datetime' => '2012/06/08 01:49:19'
      },
      {
        'Color' => 'red',
        '2nd Color' => 'blue',
        '3rd Color' => 'green',
        'toy' => 'truck',
        'toy_type' => 'chevy',
        'kind' => '4door',
        'Stage' => 'Production',
        'Step' => 'Platform',
        'Datetime' => '2012/06/08 01:52:14'
      },
      {
        'Color' => 'white',
        '2nd Color' => 'blue',
        '3rd Color' => 'yellow',
        'toy' => 'truck',
        'toy_type' => 'gmc',
        'kind' => '4door',
        'Stage' => 'Production',
        'Step' => 'Platform',
        'Datetime' => '2012/06/08 06:24:14'
      },
```

Notice how I only wanted the most recent ford and recent chevy to be stored, but because there was only one gmc, I also wanted that stored.

I was referring to the perldsc (http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html) documentation, but it did not go into this great of detail. Is this even possible?

Comment: Variants of this already covered several times: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bperl%5D+sort+hash+multiple

Comment: These links are to sort Hashes, the sorting is already done, im looking to create a new hash with only certain elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
sub key { join ':', @{ $_[0] }{qw( toy kind Stage Step )} }

# Determine which records to keep.
my %latest;
for my $rec (@$recs) {
    my $key = key($rec);
    $latest{$key} = $rec->{Datetime}
       if !$latest{$key} || $latest{$key} lt $rec->{Datetime};
}        

# Filter out the others.
@$recs = grep { $latest{key($_)}{Datetime} eq $_->{Datetime} } @$recs;
```

The above method preserves the original order. It also handles ties elegantly (keeps both).

If you don't need to preserve the original order, you can use something simpler. Unfortunately, it only keeps one record in the event of a tie, and its performance doesn't scale as well [O(N log N) instead of O(N)].

```
sub key { join ':', @{ $_[0] }{qw( toy kind Stage Step )} }

my %seen;
@$recs =
   grep !$seen{key($_)}++,
    sort { $b->{Datetime} cmp $a->{Datetime} }
     @$recs;
```

(Add a `reverse` in front of `grep` if you want the final result sorted by ascending `Datetime`.)

Comment: Added an alternative solution to my Answer.

Comment: Thanks, Ikegami. I will try and implement this logic and get back to you with the results. Additionally, original order does not matter as I have a back end sorting method and a tie will never occur, so only keeping one record would be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using a hash of hashes instead?  You could then use the make of the vehicles as the key in the outer hash and any previous entry would be automatically overwritten, so you would end up with only the latest entry of each make.

Comment: I had considered that, but I am stuck with arrays of hashes for other reasons. Thanks for the thought though Dave.

Answer (score 0):

Your data doesn't seem to be very representative, firstly because the key fields `toy`, `kind`, `Stage` and `Step` are identical in all records, and also because the data isn't sorted as you say it is (at least it's not sorted by date/time as I hope you meant).

This code will return a list of the earliest unique records in the data. Given your data it returns just the fourth record as it is dated `2012/06/08 01:24:14` which is earlier than all the rest.

```
my %seen;

my @filtered = grep {
  not $seen{join '|', @$_{qw/ toy kind Stage Step /} }++
}
sort {
  $a->{Datetime} cmp $b->{Datetime}
} @data;
```

Comment: This was just a fraction of the code I was dealing with. There were multiple entries for toys and kinds, but I didnt want to post an overabundance of code. Thanks though